# How to display alert messages in PhoneGap Javascript iOs Mobile App?

Tags: javascript, ios, alert, phonegap

I'm building this app for ios and android with phonegap framework. By the way, I have my apple certificates from developer program so everything is working fine there. I'm able to compile ios, android and windows apps with PhoneGap Build. The entire app works very well in Android. The problem is with ios. Alert messages never pop up.

Something like this would display in Android

```
alert("You are the winner!");
```

The same alert box will not display in ios, nothing happens. All the alert messages I have implemented in the ios phone do not trigger. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Install `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs`

Then you can try these methods

```
navigator.notification.alert
navigator.notification.confirm
navigator.notification.prompt
navigator.notification.beep
```

Example: 
navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])

```
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```